# Need help with either globaldict or saving to JSON and recalling the saved info

Tags: game-engine, saving

So I've tried using the globaldict to make int properties persist across different scenes, but it doesn't work no matter how I try.

I've followed many tutorials exactly and to the letter, but in the newest version of UPBGE it just does not work. I tried using logic nodes to call the variable in one scene from an object with a variable on it, save it to a JSON file and tried saving it to globaldict as well.

However when I try to call the saved variable in another scene the console says something like it refuses to import the saved variable to scene without an exception.

I'm so lost. There must be a new way. Please I've asked so many people but they all just ghost me or talk trash. I've looked at the whole you scene is a ship illustration but that is way outdated. I would very much love a video showing how you would do this. Or at the very least a step by step instructions guide. Having variables sent and read in other scenes is absolutely necessary to make any decent game.

Comment: Tutorial requests are off-topic. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic. I don't think a tutorial is needed for this. If you don't get answers, it is because of the vagueness of the question. There aren't many UPBGE users around, so you should make it as clear and specific as possible if you hope to get any answer. Share the code you have tried. If you get an error message, copy it exactly. Don't know about UPBGE, but you can write to a text file with Python in Blender. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp